# the content of one column is not in line with the next column webpage html css

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner html and css coder. I have a page where I divided the main body into two columns with some text in the first column and a set of tabs in the second column. However the top of the tabs do not align with the top of the text in the first column. I have tried different ways but nothing seems to work for me.

[This is the webpage that I am creating showing the set of tabs not aligning with the text(from "Create New" down) in the first column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I97um.png)

This is the html code:

```
<html>

<head>

<div class="MainHead">
    <h1>Doors 'n' More</h1>
    <h3>Creating Openings to Success</h3>
    <p>Help, User Profile</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Page1.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="HomeBody">

    <div class="Column1">
        <h2>Create New</h2> 
        <h2>Shortcuts</h2> 
        <h2>Recent Items</h2> 
        <h2>Messages and Alerts</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="BodyTabs">

        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="HomeTab" name="TabGroup1" checked>
            <label for="HomeTab">Home</label>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="Column2">
                    <h2>Feed</h2> 
                    <h2>Active Jobs</h2>
                </div>  

                <div class="Column3">
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="ProjectsTab" name="TabGroup1">
            <label for="ProjectsTab">Projects</label>
            <div class="content">
                All Projects go on this tab.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="CustomersTab" name="TabGroup1">
            <label for="CustomersTab">Customers</label>
            <div class="content">
                All Customers go on this tab.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="DashboardTab" name="TabGroup1">
            <label for="DashboardTab">Dashboard</label>
            <div class="content">
                The Dashboard goes on this tab.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the css code:

```
.MainHead{
padding: 5px; 
}
.HomeBody{
width: 100%;
height:800px;
}
.Column1{
width: 20%;
float:left;
}
.BodyTabs{
position: relative;   
min-height: 200px;
clear: both;
width: 80%;
float: right;
}
.tab{
float: left
}
.tab label{
background: #eee; 
padding: 10px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
margin-left: -1px; 
position: relative;
left: 1px;    
}
.tab [type=radio] {
display: none;   
}
.content {
position: absolute;
top: 28px;
left: 0;
background: white;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
height: 700px;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
z-index: 1;
}
.Column2{
width: 75%;
float:left;
}
.Column3{
width: 25%;
float:left;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to remove "clear: both;" from .BodyTabs, if you can put your code in codepen so people can try your code that would be better.

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgMvwM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `clear: both` on your floated elements. `clear: both` should be used to separate **rows**, not columns that are next to each other. You're essentially stating that you want the second column to not float next to the first column. Simply remove `clear: both` from `.BodyTabs` to get the desired result:

```
.BodyTabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bxcurn9e/).

Note that this will simply shift the two columns next to each other. If you want the top of the tabs to be perfectly flush with the top of 'Create New', you'll also need a bit of a margin at the top of `.BodyTabs`:

```
.BodyTabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

A secondary fiddle showing this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bxcurn9e/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks to all who mentioned the clear:both error. I have got rid of it and it works much better thanks :) It also solved my next question in regards to rows!! @ObsidianAge